# In javascript, how do you change the value of a property whose type is "number"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
typeof document.getElementById('foo').bar('value') //returns "number"
```

I want to change the 'value'.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('foo').bar('value')) // 10
```

I can't just the value to a number, it will rightfully throw an errror:

```
document.getElementById('foo').bar('value')) = 12 // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
10 = 12 // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

How would you set the value of bar?

This particular instance is for the slider offered by jquery, so the actual code (with me attempting to change its value looks like this:

```
$('#slider').slider.val(function (index, value) {
  return value + '' + deltaY + '%'})
```

However I'm returned a long error which is pasted here: https://gist.github.com/2e65bbf1578f7ea27bb0

> "...}has no method 'val'"

Comment: What is that ominous `bar` function of HTML elements?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: `.bar()` is a method. What does it do?

Comment: .bar is equal to .slider, I was originally framing this using just Javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the value property of input elements, it always is a string (and will be converted to one when setting).

The invocation of the `bar()` method returns a value (not a "pointer"), and you cannot assign to that of course. What you need to do that the function returns a different result obviously depends heavily on that function.

---

The [error you get](https://gist.github.com/2e65bbf1578f7ea27bb0) comes from the expression `$('#slider').slider.val...` - `$.fn.slider`, the function you access here, *has no property "val"* (which you therefore cannot invoke). What are you trying to do there? Read the documentation for that slider plugin you use carefully.

Comment: Good point, just now found what I was looking for, sorry if I may have wasted someone's time, here's the relevant info: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-value

Get or set the value option, after init:
//setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 37 );

Answer (score 0):

Whatever this is:

```
$('#slider').slider
```

Has not method call `val()`

Therefore calling `$('#slider').slider.val(...)` is obviously not going to work.

Haven't tested it, but maybe `slider` should be a function that returns an object?

`$('#slider').slider().val(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the title and the first part of this question are a red herring.

I believe that you are trying to use the JQuery UI slider method? If so then do as Bergi suggests and read the docs. If I'm understanding your needs correctly then you should pay attention to the following found here:
 http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

under 'options' tab in the 'value' section:

Code examples
Initialize a slider with the value option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({ value: 37 });
```

Get or set the value option, after init.

```
//getter
var value = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 37 );
```